# Weird Vue Render issue on embedded list that uses Vuetify Badges

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity

I have a list of users that I'm trying to add an icon to enable/disable their account.  So I render the list of users in a v-for loop.  And I track the visibility of a badge on each icon with an array indexed by the loop index.

I'm having a weird issue where Vue doesn't recognize the change to the array value unless I update some other dummy variable.  Is this a Vuetify issue.  Or just a Vue Reactivity issue?

I created a Codepen that show my issue.
https://codepen.io/DedicatedManager/pen/eYmZRQo?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid class="text-center">
      The two lists are the same differing only by changing a dummy variable in the "mouseover" and "mouseout" function that causes the badge to display/hide.  But the one on the left doesn't show the badge on hover.  The one on the right has the extra dummy variable that somehow forces the rendering to work and thus the badge shows (it shows on both sides because they use the same variable to hold the boolean for the v-model.
      <v-row
        justify="space-between"
      >

        <v-col cols="6" class="mt-12">  
          <div v-for="(listItem,index) in myData" :key="index">
            <v-badge v-model="showCircle1[index]" overlap>
              <template v-slot:badge>
                <span><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></span>
              </template>
              <v-icon large color="grey" @mouseover="showCircle1[index]=true;" @mouseout="showCircle1[index]=false;">mdi-email</v-icon>
            </v-badge>
          </div>
        </v-col>


        <v-col cols="6" class="mt-12">  
          <div v-for="(listItem,index) in myData" :key="index">
            <v-badge v-model="showCircle1[index]" overlap>
              <template v-slot:badge>
                <span><v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon></span>
              </template>
              <v-icon large color="grey" @mouseover="showCircle1[index]=true; mouseOverVal=true" @mouseout="showCircle1[index]=false; mouseOverVal=false">mdi-email</v-icon>
            </v-badge>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      mouseOverVal: {{mouseOverVal}}<br>
      showCircle1: {{showCircle1}}<br>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      showCircle1:[false,false,false,false],
      myData:['one','two','three','four'],
      mouseOverVal:false,
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: I have a feeling it's because it's an array element that the reactivity doesn't kick in. In which case you need to replace it with a new array each time, not just set an element.

Answer (score 0):

Vue cannot detect changes when you set the value of an item in an array.

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats:

> For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }
})
vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
```

> [...] both of the following will accomplish the same
> as vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue, but will also trigger state
> updates in the reactivity system:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
// Array.prototype.splice
vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

See the link for further details and additional related approaches.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have realized that.  I work with objects so much I forgot about arrays.  Here's the working fix: https://codepen.io/DedicatedManager/pen/QWwNOPV?editors=1010

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. Don't forget to tick and upvote answers that are helpful.